# how to search rows using regex in mysql for values greater than x

Tags: mysql, regex

I have the following list:

- CENTURYLINK PURE BROADBAND 8M
- CENTURYLINK PURE BROADBAND 8M
- CENTURYLINK PURE BROADBAND 8M
- CENTURYLINK HIGH-SPEED INTERNET 20M/896K
- CENTURYLINK HIGH-SPEED INTERNET 12M/896K
- CENTURYLINK HIGH-SPEED INTERNET 7M/896K
- CENTURYLINK HIGH-SPEED INTERNET 12M/896K
- CENTURYLINK HIGH-SPEED INTERNET 7M/896K
- CENTURYLINK HIGH-SPEED INTERNET 12M/896K

I need to retrieve all the rows that has the internet speed greater than 8M. I am using the following query

```
SELECT * FROM century_link.orderdetail where offer_name REGEXP '([1-8]\d+|8)'
```

The above select returns the speeds greater than 8M, BUT  if you see i have one row that is 7M/896K but this row cannot be returned because 7M is less than 8M.

How can i change my select to avoid this row of being returned?

any help is appreciated.

thank you.

Comment: I would suggest doing pre-processing of data and making another float column of how many Megabits (or whatever you choose), so that you don't need to run a complicated regular expression every time and you can index it if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is:

The regex matches the number 896.

This one might be better:
([1-8]\d+M|8M|9M)

You can play with this one a bit: http://regex101.com/